# cv2 digit-image postprocessing

Tags: python, image-processing, classification, opencv

I`m trying to implement the digits classifier by myself. And I faced some troubles with it. I'm training the NN on MNIST handwritten dataset, [MNIST sample digit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LnMq.jpg). But when I'm trying to predict what the digit is, I predicted from the image that I found and processed using **cv2** - [cv2 processed digit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODv85.jpg), as you can see, my own image has a fatter circuit and clear boundaries.

That is my digit-image before the processing - [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmG1f.jpg), and after -  [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODv85.jpg). But I want to image be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCda2.jpg).
after the processing. 
I use the following code to process each digit:

```
def main():
    image = cv2.imread('digit.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = image.reshape((32,32,1))
    image = postprocess(image)

def postprocess(gray):
    kernel_size = 15
    blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size), 0)

    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 3)

    return thresh
```

I use 11 as a Threshold parameter to discard most artifacts, but my digit circuit is still bold/fat and have too clear boundaries.

Question is: how can I process the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPugd.jpg) to make it look like a [training sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LnMq.jpg)(thicker and with blurred boundaries)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by using **kernel filtering**. Today I stumbled upon an [article about kernel image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)), there were some kernels for "Edge detection", I have tried them all, but no one of them was good enough. But I did my own kernel by an oversight, and it working awesomely for me!
So, there is the code:

```
def main():
    image = cv2.imread('digit.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = postprocess(image)
    image = image.reshape((32,32,1))

def postprocess(gray):
    gray_big = cv2.resize(gray, (256,256))

    kernel = np.array([[0,-2,0],[-2,10,-2],[0,-2,0]])
    filtered = cv2.filter2D(gray_big, -1, kernel)

    filtered = 255 - filtered
    filtered = filtered / 255
    filtered = cv2.resize(filtered, (32,32))

    return filtered
```

Resizing the image to a bigger one keeps the image clear from "artifacts" after the kernel processing, I've tried to do it on a original image size, but the image wasn't so clear as in my final code version.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KefJ5.jpg)